# No deleted entries in journal receivers?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, journaling

We have all Future 3 files journaled, but when I do a DSPJRN command OUTFILFMT(*TYPE3) I have no delete (DL) entries.  I have only one record in the physical file, but many add (PT) and update (UP) entries for that one record.  How is that possible?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities. Either CLRPFM command was used to clear the table or all records in table were deleted using single delete command. If you delete all records from table using single delete command, DB2 for i will use CLRPFM. There will be entry in journal receiver for CLRPFM instead of entry for delete in both cases.

Comment: Deleting all records only issues CLRPFM if there are a sufficient number of records being deleted. This is documented. What I can't find documentation for is how they determine how many records is enough, but from what I've noticed on our system, it's probably 1000 records or so.

Comment: I checked on our system. It uses CLRPFM even when table has only one or two records. I found journal entries for CLRPFM instead of entries for delete when table has only two records. It is possible that new versions of OS might be working differently.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your thoughts.  We determined that the journal was set up to save *AFTER images only.  Since the *AFTER images were just blanks, there was no way to know which record was deleted.  We changed the journaling to *BOTH images and now can see which record(s) were deleted.